# ReferenceError: JSENCRYPT_VERSION is not defined after JSEncrypt 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, angular, exception, jsencrypt

I was using `jsencrypt 3.0.0-rc.1` and updated to `3.0.0` just now. Now I am having a following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: JSENCRYPT_VERSION is not defined.

**Temporary Solution**
: I could get rid of that error by replacing `import JSEncrypt from 'jsencrypt'` with `import JSEncrypt from 'jsencrypt/bin/jsencrypt.min.js'`

Found via [GitHub](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/issues/193)

Question:
Is there any cleaner solution to this or just have to wait for good fix by the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update to the `3.0.1` and you are good to go. No more hacks needed.